# Faces on 3D model not rendering in the correct

Tags: rendering, monogame, models

I seem to be having trouble with rendering models in monogame. I'm trying to draw several cubes, in a minecraft style world. It's a simple .obj file, nothing special. But... for whatever reason, both the top and the bottom are rendering over the sides, as can be seen here in these four cubes.

[image: here's the problem]

My code is simple as can be, so I can't imagine the problem is directly the fault of this:

```
public static void DrawModel(Model model, Matrix modelspace, Texture2D texture)
    {

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {

                //effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.TextureEnabled = true;
                effect.Texture = texture;
                effect.World = modelspace;
                effect.View = Cameraworks.ActiveCamera.View;
                effect.Projection = Cameraworks.ActiveCamera.Projection;
            }

            mesh.Draw();
        }

    }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Looks like some of your normals are inverted... Check in your 3D editor to make sure they're pointing outward.

Comment: Normals inverted, like @AlexandreVaillancourt said, or somehow your meshes are going ACB instead of ABC (vertex direction).

Comment: Any clue would I go about fixing the latter problem? How would I make them go in the correct order...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, it was because of a previous SpriteBatch call causing the GraphicsDevice settings to be changed. Putting this code in before my model drawing code executed fixed it, and now it draws correctly.

```
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
```